# React Styleguidist - Web Component doesn't load on index.html

Tags: reactjs, web-component, react-styleguidist

I have a style guide for a [react web component library](https://github.com/geops/trafimage-maps)

When loading the [base URL](https://trafimage-maps.geops.ch/), the sections load as expected and everything works.

When I load the [base URL/index.html](https://trafimage-maps.geops.ch/index.html) (e.g. by switching back to "Components" after loading "Layers" in the top right tabs), the same page should be loaded, but the web component fails to load with no errors. When checking out the examples, errors are thrown, presumably because they can't access the web component.

My guess is some adjustments should be made in the [style guide config](https://github.com/geops/trafimage-maps/blob/master/styleguide.config.js). Does anyone have any hints? I am fairly new to web components, so I am pretty much in the dark atm

Thanx